# TableView: How to select another row's value from didSelectRowAtIndexPath routine

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

When didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called, it's easy to get a cell's text value using:
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
entryText = cell.textLabel.text;

However, I'm having a problem figuring out how to get the cell text value from another row at the same time. For instance, if a user clicks on row 0, the above will get me the cell text from row 0. But I need to get the cell text from row 1 and row 2.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your own IndexPath variable for those cells, for example:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
UITableViewCell *cell1 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath1];
NSString *cell1Text = [NSString stringWithString: cell1.textLabel.text];

NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+2 inSection:indexPath.section];
UITableViewCell *cell2 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath2];
NSString *cell2Text = [NSString stringWithString: cell2.textLabel.text];
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! One other question, though. My tables have multiple sections. Rather than hardcoding the inSection number, how do I pull that value?

Comment: If the rows are in the same section use the NSIndexPath sent so NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:indexPath.section];

Comment: Thank you all. Works great. Last question is how to extract the section header text?

Comment: Like the other guys you should really be pulling this from your data model. But if you had to do it this way I'll create an NSMutableArray and when you create the section header add a string object to the array. Then pull that out when you need it and have the section id from the indexPath. Can you mark this as the answer ;).

Answer (score 3):

Simply ask your model for the data. You should never use views to store data. This is especially important for table view cells where the data in the view can be gone from one moment to the next as the user scrolls a cell off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you are storing the datasource for the table.  If it's in an array, then you simply index into the array to get the value.